# Does a snapahot of elasticsearch that ended with ‘success’ state, can have missing index documents?

Tags: api, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, indexing, snapshot

I have a snapahot I did that ended in 'success' state.
but I wonder, is that necessarily means that all the documents inside the index that have been snapshotted, were indeed snapshotted?
it has been said in their documentation that it means all shards were available and got snapshoted,
which means that all indices were snapshotted but what about the docs inside? is there any
validation about them? any index docs count check??

Comment: As documents are stored inside the shards, if the shards have been successfully snapshotted, so are the documents inside them.

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch team member confirms:
Yes, "success" means that all the data from the index was successfully snapshotted.